# Que significa los corchetes en esta linea de c++

Tags: c++

Estoy checando el codigo tetris en consola de aca
 https://github.com/OneLoneCoder/videos/blob/master/OneLoneCoder_Tetris.cpp

Y no entiendo esta linea de codigo

```
screen[(y + 2)*nScreenWidth + (x + 2)] = L" ABCDEFG=#"[pField[y*nFieldWidth + x]];
```

Basicamente los corchetes que encierran a pField

Comment: A mi me parece que es un arreglo de `char`: `" ABCDEFG=#"` y seleccionas el indice con el valor: `[pField[y*nFieldWidth + x]]` lo que yo no entiendo es la `L`

Comment: si quisiera saber como se llama ese metodo para indexar un string para buscar mas info, segun el creador L indica al compilador que el string es Unicode String .

Answer (score 2):

Los corchetes (`[` y `]`) son el operador de indizado, que es un [azúcar sintáctico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Az%C3%BAcar_sint%C3%A1ctico) de aritmética de punteros, la expresión `p[10]` siendo `p` un puntero, es equivalente a `*(p + 10)`<sup>1</sup> tal y como se indica en [el estándar](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (traducción mía):

> #### 6.5.2.1 Subindizado de Formaciones
>
> 2. Una expresión postfija seguida de una expresión entre corchetes `[]` es la designación subindizada de un elemento de un objeto formación. La definición del operador de subindizado `[]` es que `E1[E2]` es idéntico a `(*((E1)+(E2)))`. Dadas las reglas de conversión que se aplican al operador binario `+`, si `E1` es un objeto formación (de manera equivalente, un puntero al elemento inicial de un objeto formación) y `E2` es un entero, `E1[E2]` designa el `E2`ésimo elemento de `E1` (contando desde cero).

Por otro lado, en C++ los literales de texto son formaciones<sup>2</sup> constantes de tamaño precalculado, así que el tipo de `L" ABCDEFG=#"` es `wchar_t[11]`. Como cualquier formación, se puede usar el operador de indizado (Los corchetes `[` y `]`) para acceder a uno de los elementos de la formación.

---

- <sup>1</sup>Esto implica que `p[10]` y `10[p]` son equivalentes, por absurdo que parezca.
- <sup>2</sup>También conocidas como arreglos o en inglés *array*.